# Ap-hotspot wifi clients can't reach each other

Tags: 12.04, hot-spot

I am using ap-hotspot to create a wireless access point for 2 computers and a phone. Everything is working correctly but I cannot reach from one client connected to the access point another client.

If I ping the pc executing Ap-Hotspot it responds, also, if I ping from a client the computer executing Ap-Hotspot also works. But, if I ping from one client, the other client, I cannot reach it.

I'm not really sure if this is a Ap-Hotspot configuration or something related to routing or forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable IP forwarding.

Edit /etc/sysctl.conf and search for the following lines:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Restart your networking services, or reboot.